# getting UserProfile

Tags: user-profile-property

I am getting user profile info like this but I have to split and get from anchors (a href) or on a query. why I can't get directly the data insted of a html dom?

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var CurrentUser = {         
          AccountName: '<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="AccountName" TitleMode="true" runat="server" />'.split("accountname=")[1].split("\">")[0],
          UserName: '<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="UserName" TitleMode="true" runat="server" />',
          FirstName: '<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="FirstName" TitleMode="true" runat="server" />',
          LastName: '<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="LastName" TitleMode="true" runat="server" />',
          PictureURL: $('<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="PictureURL" TitleMode="true" runat="server" />').attr("href"),
          Status: '<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="SPS-StatusNotes" TitleMode="true" runat="server" />'
        };  

        $("#lblUserName").html(CurrentUser.FirstName + " " + CurrentUser.LastName);
        $("#imgProfilePicture").attr("src", CurrentUser.PictureURL);
        $("#lnkEditProfile").attr("href", "/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx?accountname=" + CurrentUser.AccountName);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have SP2013, you should access the user profile properties via the [client object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx), or via the corresponding [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx) endpoint, instead of downloading the `EditProfile.aspx` page and parsing the page.

See [this post](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html) and [this one](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/01/01/programmatically-createretrieve-user-profileuser-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-2013/) as well for code samples.

If you have a pre-SP2013 version, the best choice might be to call the [User Profiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981571.aspx) web service. In this case I suggest to use the corresponding objects of the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService) library.